# How to get the current url within a React / Gatsby Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used the following to get the url within a function component.

```
const Header = () => {
  const url = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.href : '';
```

But I am looking to do the same for a class component so i can use Ternary.

Any idea how this can be done? I am struggling to find details outside of a functional component.

Comment: Use the exact same line?

Comment: you can use pathname inside the location prop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jonrsharpe I was overcomplicating the issue.

I have done what I need with the following:

```
render() {
    const url = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.href : '';

    return ( ...
```

Thank's for your pointers